# Kivy GridLayout accessing rows and cols returns None.

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code:

```
class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Board(Widget):

    my_layout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_my_layout(self, instance, value):
        print self.my_layout.cols

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Board()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And this is my kv file:

```
<Board>:
    my_layout: my_layout
    MyGridLayout:
        id: my_layout
        cols: 10
        rows: 10
```

On method `on_my_layout` I want to print how many cols my instance of MyGridLayout has. But, it returns to me always None. If I want to access rows, it returns None too. What I have to change on my python code or on my kivy language to access the right values of `MyGridLayout`'s rows and cols? It must return `rows = 10` and `cols = 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Board>:
    my_layout: my_layt ## This
    MyGridLayout:
        id: my_layt
        cols: 10
        rows: 10
```

It doesn't work, because you assign non-existing widget to `ObjectProperty`, therefore `YourObjectProperty.cols==None`. You'd basically need to do this:

```
<Board>:
    MyGridLayout:
        id: my_layt
        cols: 10
        rows: 10
    my_layout: my_layt ## This
```

which will raise an error in kv. However if you do that in `__init__()`, so your widget is already there and working, it'll print it without problems. Don't use the same names for both id and variable, otherwise it may not work at all.

```
class Board(Widget):

    my_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_layout = self.ids.my_layt
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. Can you tell me why the method `on_my_layout` is being called firstly than `__init__`?

Comment: @Caaarlos not the method, _the assigning is first_. The method is called when you change `my_layout` which is in .py an `ObjectProperty`, so when you assign something to that in .kv, then it'll run your `on_my_layout` and prints something. This is why you need to wait until the widget is initialized and then assign an initialized(present) widget to a variable, that will call your function. The first code in my answer: widget is not there when `my_layout: my_layt`.

Comment: Thank you, now I know what is happening on my code!